# Invoking PresentationSettings from an HTA

Tags: activex, jscript, hta

What I'm trying to do is invoke `PresentationSettings /start` from an HTA. It works fine from a normal command prompt, but when I try from an HTA, no dice. I assumed there was a permissions issue, so I made sure to run the HTA as administrator, and then the command as an administrator, like so:

```
var shellApp = new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application');

// Just open the GUI and keep command prompt open for testing
shellApp.ShellExecute("cmd", "/k PresentationSettings", "", "open", 1);
```

Unfortunately, I get the message:

`'PresentationSettings' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

If I try `dir c:\windows\system32\PresentationSettings.exe`, I get file not found, but when I try from a "normal" command prompt, it works.

Anyone know of a tip/trick/hack to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Use `WScript.Shell.Run` instead of `.Shell.Application.ShellExecute`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that I tried `WScript.Shell.Run` and `WScript.Shell.exec` already 

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function OpenFile(file) {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var f = fso.GetFile(file);
    var file_ok = f.ShortPath.toUpperCase();

    var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    ws.Run("" + file_ok + "");
}

OpenFile ('c://windows//system32//PresentationSettings.exe');

window.close();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will throw a File Not Found error when GetFile runs.